# Install mysql-server-8.0 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mysql-8.0, raspbian-buster

I have tried to search for how to install mysql-server-8.0 on Raspberry pi but couldn't get the helpful article to do that. What are the steps to install mysql 8.0 on Raspberry pi 3/4?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I tried this, I can get the following messages.
"Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However the following packages replace it:
   maria-db-server-10.0"

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment when i realised i had given you duff info!